# How to write in C, "ip -6 route add default dev wlan0"

Tags: android, c, linux, network-programming

I would like to write some C code , running in Android(linux) C program to set default route, ip -6 route add default dev wlan0.
Would appreciate if you have any idea, please let me know.

Best Regards

Comment: You can use the `system` function to execute your OS's shell commands: https://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Comment: Thank, but unfortunately system/execl did not work.. may be some socket should be used....

Answer (score 0):

System/execl should work. But remember:

- with execl you must put the full path to the executable. Also remember that you must put each parameter in its own string, and that the first parameter must be the binary program itself
- you will need to run your program with root privileges to do what you want

Comment: If you used 'system("sudo ...") then it makes sense. Try to launch your program as root.